# for some ip address python request.get is not working in browser but it is working in putty

Tags: python

I am new to python. i am accessing url. urls which are returning value is working fine in request.get but urls which are not returning anything request.get not working so i use signal function for timeout. timeout is working perfectly in putty but in browser its taking so much time and returning 500 error.

```
def handler(signum, frame):
   print("forever is over")
   raise Exception("end of time")

def loop_forever():
   import time
   import requests
   url = "http://www.64.251.13.121/firewall/firewall_status.php"
   headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 
   Safari/537.36'}
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   if response.status_code == 200:
       print('Exists')
   else :
       print('Not Exists')



signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(3)


try:
   loop_forever()
except Exception:
   print('Timeout executed')
```

Comment: why not [pass timeout argument](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) to `requests.get()`?

Comment: @buran sorry i didnt understant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't `timeout` parameter for `requests.get()` do for you?

```
import requests
def check_url(url, timeout=3):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
       print(f'{url} time-out')
       return False
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print(f'{url} Connection Error')
        return False
    else:
        return response.status_code == 200 # what if redirect? is it possible

urls = [...]
for url in urls:
    print(f"{url} : {'Exists' if check_url(url=url) else 'Not Exists'}")
```

Link to [relevant parts of the docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing directly with the IP, you don't need to provide the prefix `www`

```
def loop_forever():
   import time
   import requests
   url = "http://172.217.215.138"  # This is google's IP 'for testing'. Change it with your valid IP
   headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   if response.status_code == 200:
       print('Exists')
   else :
       print('Not Exists')

loop_forever() # -> Valid
```